# Что из себя представляет массив в языке программирования Java?

Tags: java, массивы, ооп, архитектура, объекты

Все мы знаем, что язык программирования Java является чисто объектным языком. Все сущности, с которыми нам приходится иметь дело и осуществлять какие-либо манипуляции, являются объектами (за исключением примитивов), в том числе и массивы. То бишь, если говорить совсем уж простыми словами, то любой массив является конкретным объектом в памяти. Java является сильно типизированным языком. Хоть и градация на языки со слабой и сильной типизацией данных является весьма условной, но Java, так или иначе, больше относится к языкам с сильной типизацией. Это ведёт нас к тому, что все данные имеют свой фиксированный тип (или класс, если говорить в терминах ООП). Вот здесь и вся загвоздка! Мне всегда хотелось узнать, каким образом описываются массивы, как некоторые абстрактные сущности, на физическом уровне. Я понимаю, что невозможно найти готовый класс, в котором бы была описана структура массивов, по той простой причине, что данная сущность является одной из фундаментальных (на равне с примивными типами данных) и её реализация спрятана где-то на уровне JVM или в каком-то другом месте.

Давайте рассмотрим тривиальный пример. Мы знаем, что размер любого массива является фиксированным и определяется на этапе создания самого массива. Сведения о размере массива хранятся в целочисленной переменной с одноимённым названием length. Сразу же возникает вопрос относительно этого поля. Откуда оно взялось? Где можно проследить всю эту внутреннюю логику (если можно так выразиться)? Идём далее. Создали массив в памяти, при этом сразу же указали его размер. Размер массива соответствует количеству однотипных элементов, которые могут храниться в этом массиве. И тут опять-таки вопрос. По какой логике JVM определяет количество элементов, которое нам необходимо? Точнее не совсем так. Понятное дело, что мы сами указываем размер массива, но разве количество полей для отдельно взятого типа данных не должно быть фиксированным?! Есть ли какой-нибудь код (пусть даже псевдокод), который мог бы хоть немного пролить свет на данный вопрос.

Comment: Посмотрите исходники

Comment: @Anton Sorokin Буду Вам премного благодарен, если подскажете где конкретно искать.

Comment: @Lexoid Посмотри здесь [Class Array](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html)

Comment: На уровне JVM существует всего несколько реализаций массивов. Каждый под отдельный тип хранимого содержимого. Если это примитивный тип, то для int это блок памяти размером 4 * n байт, если это ссылочный тип, то уже может быть как 4n так и 8n в зависимости от разрядности системы. Объект в массивах не хранится, в массиве хранятся только ссылки на объекты, а ссылки имеет фиксированную длину. В общем, ничего непонятного не вижу.

Comment: @Nick_Jv Вы хотите сказать, что при создании обычного массива мы просто инстанцируем класс java.lang.reflect.Array? Или Вы имели в виду что-то другое, когда ссылались в своём комментарии на этот класс?

Comment: @Serhii Dikobrazko Если я правильно Вас понял, то под "n" надо бы понимать количество элементов в созданном массиве. Верно? Но какое отношение имеет разрядность системы к величине массива? С какой бы системой мы не работали, мы всегда будем получать размер массива 4n, если мы имеем дело с массивом целочисленных значений примитивного типа данных int. А если будем работать с типами long или double, тогда размер массива будет составлять уже 8n. Или как-то не так? Можете прояснить этот момент? Вроде бы Java никак не привязана к разрядности системы, вот и возникает определённая коллизия.

Comment: @Lexoid От разрядности системы зависит размер ссылки на объект. В 64х разрядной они в два раза больше. Потому в 32х перхеменная int занимает в действительности занимает 128 бит, а в 64х - 224 битв. Размер примитивов для массивов остается неизменным, но тут я утверждать не буду. Там свои тонкости есть, типа как переменная boolean вроде бы она может хранить свое значение только в одном бите, но вместо этого использует память как полноценная переменная byte 8 бит.

Comment: https://www.slideshare.net/cnbailey/java-code-to-java-heap Просмотрите это. Полезно

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Надеюсь мой ответ Вам поможет. Также прикрепил ссылки на источники, для подробного изучения.

- В Java, массивы являются объектами и наследуются от `Object`
- Переменные в массиве упорядочены, индексация массива начинается с  0.

Когда мы создаем объект массива с помощью `new`, в куче выделяется под это дело память и возвращает нам ссылку. Но как так получается? Тип массива записывается как `type []`, где `type` - тип данных содержащихся элементов; скобки`[]` - это специальные символы, указывающие, что эта переменная содержит массив; число которое передаем в `new int[5]` - размер нашего массива.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Что представляет собой массив Java в памяти?](https://www.programcreek.com/2013/04/what-does-a-java-array-look-like-in-memory/)

- Размер массива не является частью его типа, поэтому скобки пустые
  `int[] array;`
- массив объектов будет содержать ссылки на эти объекты, а если он пока не инициализирован, то `null` ([Значения по умолчанию  в Java](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/default-array-values-in-java/))

Подробнее про массивы можно почитать тут: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Чтобы подробнее понять как создается массив рассмотрим эквивалентную запись:

```
String[] array = (String[]) Array.newInstance(String.class, 3);
```

эта запись равна этой:

```
String[] array = new String[3];
```

метод `(Class<?> componentType, int length)` возвращает нам `newArray(componentType, length)`, а вот уже реализация `newArray()` является `native`. И этот прекрасный и скрытый от наших глаз метод возвращает нам наш массив и дальше мы приводим к `class [Ljava.lang.String` с помощью `(String[]) Array.newInstance(String.class, 3)`.

Ссылки на источники:

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html
- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/arrays-in-java/

На уровне JVM, на примере `int[]`:

- Новый массив целых чисел создается во время выполнения операции
  `newarray int`
- Размер массива должен быть в стеке до выполнения этой операции; операция оставляет в стеке ссылку на массив. Ссылки загружаются и сохраняются с помощью операций `iaload var` и `iastore var`.

Стоит сказать, что на уровне JVM в зависимости от типа будут вызваны соответствующие команды. Подробнее: https://www.artima.com/underthehood/objectsP.html

- если ссылка на массив находится в верхней части стека, операция `arraylength` оставит длину массива поверх стека.
  И наверное как раз ее нам возвращает метод `Array.getLength(array)`

Подробнее:

- https://cs.nyu.edu/courses/fall00/V22.0201-001/jvm3.html

Comment: Получается что от массива можно наследоваться?

Comment: @Flippy он помечен `final` наверно

Comment: Действительно, если кому интересно, то я только что посмотрел исходный текст класса java.lang.reflect.Array, как оказалось, он и вправду помечен модификатором final при объявлении. К сожалению, унаследоваться от него не удастся.

Comment: А вообще огромное спасибо за ответ! Многое стало ясно. Теперь я понял, что реализация самого массива, как некоторой абстрактной сущности, описана в классе java.lang.reflect.Array

Comment: То есть, я реально при желании могу использовать чисто такую форму записи: String[] array = (String[]) Array.newInstance(String.class, 3); ? Очень интересно, честно говоря, я даже подумать об этом не мог. Сколько учили меня, ни разу даже не упоминалось об этом. Постоянно рассказывали, будто бы массивы являются одной из фундаментальных единиц самого языка и их реализация где-то очень глубоко скрыта, подальше от наших глаз.

Comment: И ещё такой вот интересный вопрос возник. Ответьте на него, если можно. В общем, мне захотелось понять, зачем мы явным образом используем приведение результата выполнения метода newInstance(Class<?> componentType, int length) класса java.lang.reflect.Array; Мне казалось, что этот метод и так должен возвращать массив необходимого нам типа, так как мы передаём в сам метод, в качестве одного из фактических параметров, необходимый нам класс при помощи рефлексии. Если не совершать явного приведения, то можно увидеть, что мы получили на выходе объект класса java.lang.Object

Comment: В общем-то сам вопрос, что мы подразумеваем в данном случае под сущностью класса Object? Нам возвращается непосредственно наш созданный массив, который затем обобщённо рассматривается, как экземпляр класса Object? Другого варианта я не вижу, так как нисходящее преобразование к типу String[] в ином случае было бы невозможно. А какой же тогда реальный тип нашего объекта мы получаем на выходе? Что-то типа того же Array? Или там что-то другое лежит на самом деле? Спасибо! :)

Comment: SeeSharp прав,он помечен как `final`

Comment: @Lexoid В самой документации написано, что класс `Array` предоставляет статические методы для динамического создания и доступа к массивам Java.

Comment: @Lexiod Я предполагаю, что на выходе мы получаем `Object `. JVM знает как построен этот объект и знает к какому типу можно его преобразовать или `ClassCastException `  (что можно проверить, например: `Object array = (String) Array.newInstance(String.class, 3)` , а вот `Object array = (String[]) Array.newInstance(String.class, 3)` отработает без нареканий). На эту тему у меня не получилось ничего найти, поэтому извиняйте, точно что происходит сказать не могу.